# Create a transaction in PHP with INNODB 5.6.42-84.2

Tags: php, xampp

I want to use mysqli_begin_transaction() function but I receive this error

```
Warning: mysqli_begin_transaction(): This server version doesn't support 'READ WRITE' and 'READ ONLY'. Minimum 5.6.5 is required
```

I read that that error is for the innodb version, but how I can do a transaction in my mysql version without an upgrade?

CODE

````
$usu = 2;
mysqli_begin_transaction($link, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);
try{
    $sql_delete = "DELETE FROM habitacion WHERE NoHabitacion=$usu"; 
    #echo "consulta".$consulta;
    mysqli_query($link, $sql_delete);
    mysqli_commit($link);
    mysqli_close($link);
} catch(Exception $e){
    mysqli_rollback($link);
}
        ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You haven't stated your version of mysql but check out the comments here, there seems to be a workaround for some users and that may work:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

Otherwise if you actually are on an old mysql version you probably need to upgrade that thing.